# Remove line from file if containing word from another .txt file in python/bash

Tags: python, bash, csv, lines

I'm learning python, and then i have the following difficulties.
The file i want to be cleaned is an .csv file.
The file that contains the words that have to be removed from the .csv file is an .txt
The .txt file is a list of domain names:

```
domain.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
```

The .csv file is a config file just like this:

```
domain.com;8;Started;C:\inetpub\wwwroot\d\domain.com;"http *:80:www.domain.com"
```

if the .txt file contains "domain.com" i want the complete line above to be removed.
I would be realy gratefully if some python ninja could fix this.(or in bash?)

Comment: You don't need a Python ninja for this;  `grep` would suffice.  See `man grep`.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried many python scripts, but they only allow the file directly in the cod, i want to do it from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since OP is learning python ...

`$ python SCRIPT.py`

```
TXT_file = 'TXT.txt'
CSV_file = 'CSV.csv'
OUT_file = 'OUTPUT.csv'

## From the TXT, create a list of domains you do not want to include in output
with open(TXT_file, 'r') as txt:
    domain_to_be_removed_list = []

    ## for each domain in the TXT
    ## remove the return character at the end of line
    ## and add the domain to list domains-to-be-removed list
    for domain in txt:
        domain = domain.rstrip()
        domain_to_be_removed_list.append(domain)


with open(OUT_file, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(CSV_file, 'r') as csv:

        ## for each line in csv
        ## extract the csv domain
        for line in csv:
            csv_domain = line.split(';')[0]

            ## if csv domain is not in domains-to-be-removed list,
            ## then write that to outfile
            if (not csv_domain in domain_to_be_removed_list):
                outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Will this suffice ?

```
import sys

def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as fh:
        fhDomains = fh.read().split(";")
    with open(sys.argv[2]) as fh:
        fhExcludes = fh.read().split("\n")

    for i, dom in enumerate(fhDomains):
        if dom in fhExcludes:
            del fhDomains[i]

    fh = open(sys.argv[1], "w")
    fh.write(";".join(fhDomains))





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

execute with:

> script.py Domains.txt excludes.txt

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/.*/^&;/' domains.txt) file.csv
```

@glenn jackman's suggetion - shorter.

```
grep -wFvf domains.txt file.csv
```

but, the `foo.com` in domains, will stll will match both lines (one unwanted), like:

```
foo.com;.....
other.foo.com;.....
```

soo...

my domains.txt

```
dom1.com
dom3.com
```

my file.csv (only the 1st column needed)

```
dom1.com;wedwedwe
dom2.com;wedwedwe 2222
dom3.com;wedwedwe 333
dom4.com;wedwedwe 444444
```

result:

```
dom2.com;wedwedwe 2222
dom4.com;wedwedwe 444444
```

if you have windows file - the lines ends with `\r\n` not only with `\n`, use:

```
grep -vf <(<domains.txt tr -d '\r' |sed -e 's/.*/^&;/') file.csv
```

Comment: Does not work, outputs only the content of the csvfile

Comment: @HwT Tt works. See the edit. Maybe, your domains.txt contains some other characters... In this case, you should modify the question ;)

Comment: This will be faster and safer: `grep -Fvf domains.txt file.csv`

Comment: @glennjackman Not really. :) The `fgrep` (fixed string) solution will not works if the domains.txt contains foo.com and the file.csv will contains `somefoo.com` - will removed too. So, it is __NOT__ safer... You need match the `beginning of line` and the `semicolon too`...

Comment: Well, you just need to add `-w` to the mix of options to only match whole words. I said safer because it's just doing fixed string matching, so any unintended regex chars in the domain list won't inadvertently match

Comment: @glennjackman YES. I (and you too) forgot the `-w`. With the `-w` - youre right - partially - see the edit some.foo.com ;)

Comment: @glennjackman - here is only one regex char `.` (dot) in domains. When matched the `^` and the `;` here is nearly zero probability of match something other...

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` one-liner should do the trick:

```
awk -F';' 'NR == FNR {a[$1]++; next} !($1 in a)' txtfile csvfile
```

Comment: Does not work, outputs only the content of the csvfile

Comment: @HwT Your file seems to have windows formatting. Run it by `dos2unix` command first