# Remove entire specific row in CSV

Tags: python, csv

Init file looks like this:

```
1;2019-03-20 22:43:00.934775;200;3;60;0.05;0.05;20_File_18289094.csv;2;
2;2019-03-20 22:46:42.582782;200;3;60;0.05;0.05;21_File_16565692.csv;2;
3;2019-03-20 22:46:52.971144;200;3;60;0.05;0.05;22_File_22368393.csv;
```

I want to read and remove specific row of same file, my goal is the find first column of a row, and delete it entirely. This is my code so far, but it just replacing `;` to `,`

```
1,2019-03-20 22:43:00.934775,200,3,60,0.05,0.05,20_File_18289094.csv,2,
2,2019-03-20 22:46:42.582782,200,3,60,0.05,0.05,21_File_16565692.csv,2,
3,2019-03-20 22:46:52.971144,200,3,60,0.05,0.05,22_File_22368393.csv,2,



with open(file_master) as inf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf.readlines(), delimiter=';')

with open(file_master, 'w') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for line in reader:
        if str(line[0]) == '1':
            writer.writerow(line)
            break
        else:
            writer.writerow(line)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a line from a csv if it contains a certain word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314368/how-to-remove-a-line-from-a-csv-if-it-contains-a-certain-word)

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what is the problem you are trying to solve. That said, your reader is probably not going to read anything, since by the time you try to read from it, the file it was reading from is closed (outside of the with context)

Comment: @MadWombat Hi thank I want to delete the entire row if the first column of the row is equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

This does the job.

Open the file with `r+` flag which allows read and write.

`outdata` is placeholder list for your post "clean up" content.

Loop through lines checking the first value for match with in this case `"1"`, otherwise add it to the date that will be written out.

`seek` gets you back to the beginning of the file (otherwise you get append like behavior).

Write your cleaned up content.

`truncate` gets rid of the previous data that has not yet been written over (otherwise you would get rows 2,3,3).

```
with open("file_master", 'r+') as outf:
    outdata = []
    for line in outf.read().split("\n"):
        line_items = line.split(";")
        if line_items[0] == "1":
            pass
        else:
            outdata.append(",".join(line_items))
    outf.seek(0)
    outf.write("\n".join(outdata))
    outf.truncate()
```

Comment: Hi thank u, I want to delete the entire row not just the first column, if the first column of the row is equal to 1.